# Android SDK manager giving weird error installing google play service

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am getting an error while installing google play services from SDK manager.

The error is as follows

```
    Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Google Play services, revision 31
Installing Google Play services, revision 31
Unzip failed: E:\AndroidSDK\extras\google\google_play_services\docs\reference\com\google\android\gms\auth\UserRecoverableAuthException.html (Access is denied)
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
```

please somebody help me with this what need to be done

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiii Everyone,

After 2 days finally solved my issue by blocking anti virus..It was actually was not allowing me to install some exe files for that SDK package.